# How to count how many times an event occurred in a time frame? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

As the screenshot shows, I am trying to detect VWAP rebounds and if you may see, there's a huge bearish breakout on the right side of the image. My theory is, if I could count the number of how many times a bounce occurred then (combining with the trend of VWAP) I could be able to predict potential breakouts. Also in bullish context.

**Is there a function to do this counting? Or any idea of a scripted workaround?**

I can get the moment of Market Open, it could be the best start of the counting. Couldn't make `ta.cum()` work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to count how many times your condition was true in the given length:

```
cnt = math.sum(cond ? 1 : 0, len)
```

Comment: Wow cool! And any idea, how to make the counting started from a certain event (VWAP's isNewPeriod)? I eventually couldn't resolve it. Should I post it in a new Question?

Comment: Yes, please. Always one question per post.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132665/how-to-make-the-counting-of-an-events-occurrences-started-from-the-occurrence-o Thank you. :)

Comment: Kindly let me remind you today. I extended the linked question to make the testing as easy as possible. Thank you. :)